# EHCACHE in memeory Cache hit count is showing twice for every hit in camel Fuse

Tags: ehcache, jbossfuse

in memory hits count is showing twice  the expected value in EHCACHE . is this expected behavior? When i am hitting it for the first time it correctly shows cacheMiss count as 1, but the subsequesnt hits which it reads from the cahe the hit count is always 2 for everyhit in the cache.

Am first trying to GET data the data from Cache, if not found then ADD it in the cache. In this process Hit is twice that miss.

```
<route handleFault="true" streamCache="true" id="MainRoute">
    <from uri="direct:start"/>
     <setHeader headerName="CamelCacheOperation">
      <constant>CamelCacheGet</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelCacheKey">
      <simple>${property.employeeId}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="cache://EmployeeCache"/>
    <choice>
      <when>
        <simple>${header.CamelCacheElementWasFound} == null</simple>
        <to uri="direct:AddDataRoute"/>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelCacheOperation">
          <constant>CamelCacheAdd</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelCacheKey">
          <simple>${property.employeeId}</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="cache://EmployeeCache"/>
      </when>
    </choice>
  </route>
```

=====
[Fuse Ehcache Statistics for the above senario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adgds.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the code accessing the cache. There is no know bug in the latest releases where each cache hit is counted twice.